# what's the meaning of `Webkit` in Renderer Process?

Tags: electron, webkit

I saw an architecture diagram of Electron:

[image]

I want to know what's the meaning of `Webkit` in Renderer Process?
Is it mean the BOM/DOM APIs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Webkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) refers to the browser engine (so, yes, the DOM manipulation APIs, amongst other things, will be there).

Your diagram is out of date, as the renderer process run on a recent Chromium (Chromium 106 as I write this: see https://www.electronjs.org/), and Chromium hasn't used Webkit in a number of years; it uses Blink instead.